# add the file name to the new Python column on all lines

Tags: python

I have some code that combines multiple excel files together. What I need to further do is to add a new column with the filename associated with each record.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = [item for item in glob.glob(r'../content/*{}'.format('.xlsx'))]

combined = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    file = pd.read_excel(file,
                         skiprows=1,
                         usecols=['Уровень','Код WBS','Код','Тип','Название'])
    file = file[['Уровень','Код WBS','Код','Тип','Название']]
    combined = pd.concat([combined, file])

combined.to_excel("../content/multiplesheet.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet')
```

What I need to further do is to add a new column with the filename associated with each record.

Comment: add column before you combine

Comment: don't use the same variable `file` for filename (`for file in files`) and later to keep dataframe (`file = pd.read_exce(...)`) because you loose filename.  Use standard `df = pd.read_excel(...)`. And then you can try to use `df["filename"} = file` before `concat`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added new column with filename each iteration. Try below snippet

```
combined = pd.DataFrame()
for file in files:
    file_df = pd.read_excel(file,
                         skiprows=1,
                         usecols=['Уровень','Код WBS','Код','Тип','Название'])
    file_df = file_df[['Уровень','Код WBS','Код','Тип','Название']]
    file_df['filename']=file#adding filename column with dataframe
    combined = pd.concat([combined, file_df])

combined.to_excel("../content/multiplesheet.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet')
```